# C++ Reading file

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am going to read a file and output all the elements. But when I am reading and outputting, It will just display the first element only and won't go through the second. Thank you guys first. Appreciate

```
int main（）{
    ifstream patientRead ;
    patientRead.open("Patient_List.txt") ;
    string name ,ID, address , docName , diagnosis , patientStatus , consultationDate ;
    int age ;

    if(patientRead.is_open()){
        while(getline(patientRead ,name), patientRead >> ID >> age >> address >> docName >> diagnosis >> patientStatus >> consultationDate){

            int count = 0;
            count ++ ;
            cout<< "Patient "             << count             << endl ;
            cout<< "Name              : " << name              << endl ;
            cout<< "ID                : " << ID                << endl ;
            cout<< "Address           : " << address           << endl ;
            cout<< "Doctor Name       : " << docName           << endl ;
            cout<< "Diagnosis         : " << diagnosis         << endl ;
            cout<< "Patient Status    : " << patientStatus     << endl ;
            cout<< "Consultation Date : " << consultationDate  << endl << endl;
        }        
    }else{
        cout << "Unable to open" ;
    }
    patientRead.close();
}
```

This is the pattern of the file(File Name: "Patient_List.txt"):

```
ZI ZI ZI
UMMY123456 19 NO1234 DrDomo FEVER OUTPATIENT 15/5/2021
LIM LIM LIM
UMMY987654 25 NO0987 DrDomo FEVER OUTPATIENT 15/5/2021
```

Comment: You probably want to declare `count` outside the loop.

Comment: Mixing `getline` and `>>` is tricky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: I want count +1 every time and display out

Comment: Which is why you want to declare it before the loop. Otherwise the count will be 1 every time.

Comment: If dont want mix it up, how can I do ?declare name1, name2, name3 and then Patient >> name1 >> name2 >> name3 ,  Like this? But I tried it before still cant display the LIM LIM LIM

Comment: You need to read @RetiredNinja's link. (It may not look like it's the same, but you have `>>` last in one iteration, and `getline` first in the next.)

Comment: Oh god.  Thank You for helping me. It works with adding a .get() . Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if you let the object read in its members:

```
struct Patient
{
    string name;
    string id;
    string address;
    string docName;
    string diagnosis;
    string patientStatus;
    string consultationDate;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Patient& p;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Patient& p)
{
    std::getline(input, p.name);
    input >> p.id;
    input >> p.address;
    input >> p.docName;
    input >> p.diagnosis;
    input >> p.patientStatus;
    input >> p.consultationDate;
    input.ignore(1000, '\n');
    return input;
}
```

The input loop would look like:

```
Patient p;
std::vector<Patient> database;
while (patientRead >> p)
{
    database.push_back(p);
}
```

The `getline` in the input method reads in the patient name.
The `input.ignore()` synchronizes the input to so the patient name can be read.

If you are allergic to structures and methods, you could copy and edit the content of the `operator>>` method:

```
std::getline(patientRead, name);
patientRead >> id;
patientRead >> address;
patientRead >> docName;
patientRead >> diagnosis;
patientRead >> patientStatus;
patientRead >> consultationDate;
patientRead.ignore(1000, '\n');
```